# Tkinter - Entry .get() Function

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

```
class FCMenu:
def __init__(self,master):
    frame=Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    Label(frame, text="What is the number?").grid(row=0)
    self.num = IntVar()
    self.entry = Entry(frame,textvariable=self.num).grid(row=1)
    button = Button(frame, text="Factorize", command=self.calc).grid(row=2)
    self.resultvar = StringVar()
    Label(frame, textvariable=self.resultvar).grid(row=3)

def calc(self):
    e = int(self.entry.get())
    print(e,self.num.get())
    ...
```

I am trying to create a Python GUI with tkinter, as shown above. However, every time I call `.get()` on the entry or the textvariable, it fails. With the entry itself, it explains that there is no `.get()` function for NoneType. If I remove that and use only `self.num.get()`, it prints 0 or 0.0, depending on whether or not I turn it to an integer. If I turn `self.num` to a `StringVar`, it prints nothing at all. Simply, I cannot find a way to obtain the input that I want to retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a simplified version of your code, and it prints correctly as the `Entry` widget is changed. Could be error elsewhere in your code? Or wrong indentation? Here is the code I tested with (this is 2.7 code, but worked with a 3.5 version of the code also):

```
import Tkinter as tk

class FCMenu:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = tk.Frame(master)

        self.num = tk.IntVar()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=self.num)
        self.button = tk.Button(frame, text='Calc', command=self.calc)

        frame.pack()
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button.pack()

    def calc(self):
        print(self.num.get(), self.entry.get())

root = tk.Tk()
frame = FCMenu(root)
root.mainloop()
```

It prints from both `self.num.get()` and `self.entry.get()`. The first is an `Int` and the second as `String` it seems.

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems that the grid was the issue, as your .pack() solution works perfectly.

Comment: Good that you got it to work. I think mixing pack and grid might cause problems, now that you mention it. Personally I have used only Grid for the GUIs I have made, never tried mixing them. Pack I have only used for quick tests.